# Loop through all the pivot fields values of all the pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an excel workbook and in one sheet called "RAW" I have a table like this:

**Year | Product Group | Item | Site | Category | Jan | Feb | Mar**

This table changes every month, so next month I'll have data for the months Feb Mar Apr (and so on).

Within other sheets of the workbook I have some pivot tables, all of them linked to the table of the sheet "RAW". What I want to do is, once the RAW data has changed, to execute a macro that allows me to update automatically all the pivot tables and select the three months as values (pivot fields?) for every pivot table.

I have the following code:

```
Sub Update_PT()

Dim TD As PivotTable
Dim Hoja As Worksheet

month1 = Sheets("Raw").Range("F1").Value
month2 = Sheets("Raw").Range("G1").Value
month3 = Sheets("Raw").Range("H1").Value

For Each Hoja In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each TD In Hoja.PivotTables
        TD.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next TD
Next Hoja

End Sub
```

What I am missing is to loop through all the pivot tables and set the pivot fields (or values) as my variables month1, month2, and month3.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you very much.
Best regards.

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you tried the Macro Recorder while doing it manually? This should give you at least an idea of how the code would look like. You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```
 Sub Actualizar_Tablas()

 Dim TD As PivotTable Dim Hoja As Worksheet

 month1 = Sheets("Raw").Range("G1").Value month2 =
 Sheets("Raw").Range("H1").Value month3 =
 Sheets("Raw").Range("I1").Value

 For Each Hoja In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
     For Each TD In Hoja.PivotTables
         TD.PivotCache.Refresh
         TD.AddDataField _
             Field:=TD.PivotFields(month1), _
             Function:=xlSum
         TD.AddDataField _
             Field:=TD.PivotFields(month2), _
             Function:=xlSum
         TD.AddDataField _
             Field:=TD.PivotFields(month3), _
             Function:=xlSum
     Next TD Next Hoja

 End Sub
```

But I have the following problems:

-The name of the values are "Sum of & month1" and I want them to be just month1. I am trying to change it with Caption but I am not able to.

-If I run the macro a second time I get 3 new values as "Sum of & month 1 & 2" and I want only once the values.